# Deselect selected item in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-selector

I use a `ListView` in my layout like this:

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="0.7"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
              android:divider="@color/dark_grey"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
              android:listSelector="@color/light_grey"
              android:dividerHeight="1px" />
```

The selector works great but how can I disable the selector?

I tried:

```
listView.clearChoices();
listView.setSelected();
listView.setSelector();
...
```

and a few more things but nothing works. Any ideas how I can turn my selected item back to normal? Can't be that complicated, right?

**Edit:** I need a programmatical solution!

Comment: May your are suffering from this bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754170/listview-selection-remains-persistent-after-exiting-choice-mode

Comment: Yeah, when calling `requestLayout()` after `clearChoices()` it works. If you post an anwer I'll accept it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clear ListView selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253761/how-do-i-clear-listview-selection)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Call `requestLayout()` on the `ListView` after `clearChoices()`. It will work.

Comment: for me it worked with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after  `clearChoices()`

Comment: For me worked with listviewObject.clearChoices () after adapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged ()

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated()` works for **ExpandableListView**

Comment: Let's warm up this topic. I'm trying to use this in the onDestroyActionMode method of the ActionMode.Callback and doesn't work. The only visible change happens with calling the listView.setAdapter(myAdapter); but it repositioning the screen to the top unexpectedly.

Answer (score 12):

As @Muerte mentioned above, doing the following worked for me:

```
myListView.clearChoices();
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That seems like it would be better than redrawing the whole layout.

Comment: For me worked with listviewObject.clearChoices () after adapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged ()

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked with:

```
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you. After trying so many different way, this finally worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me.  All the other suggestions didn't work.  I'm not sure why they didn't but perhaps its because I'm calling myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the onItemClick() handler.

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that the list will be recreated positioning the screen to the top. It might be annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML where you declare the ListView use:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/my_list" android:listSelector="#00000000" />
```

Comment: yeah, but i want my selector to work again for the next click on a list item... if I do this then the selector is invisible, right?

Comment: Oh maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color) can help..

Answer (score 0):

You can set a selector after click:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_white" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_white" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_white" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_white" android:state_focused="false"/>
```

and the     @drawable/transparent_white  is #00ffffff

Answer (score 0):

try this

Create your own selector xml file like this

> YourSelector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" />
</selector>
```

check out this link

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the solutions actually worked for me. My listview is for listing the searched items and has a provision to redo the search. On getting the result I added the following code snippet and it worked :)

myAdapter.setSelectedIndex(-1);

Comment: What type is your myAdapter? I couldn't find this method neither for ListView nor for ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector resource seems to be wrong here. You should use a drawable with transparent background, and i think this is what actually colors your rows, but not `choiceMode` of the `ListView`. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253761/deselect-list-if-typing-in-text/48294683#48294683) another answer for more details.