# ListView row is not clickable after adding button to the row

Tags: android, android-listview

Currently, I have a `ListView` row. Clicking any area on the row, will yield `ListView` click events.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        this.getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());
        this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewOnItemClickListener());
    } else {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754170/listview-selection-remains-persistent-after-exiting-choice-mode
        this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListViewOnItemLongClickListener());
        this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewOnItemClickListener());
    }
```

Now, for each row, I would like to add a small button. Clicking on the small button will yield button click event, which is different from `ListView` original click event.

[image]

In my `ArrayAdapter`, I use to have

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.watchlist_row_layout, null);
        ...
    }

    Button button = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utils.showLongToast("BUTTON CLICK");
        }
    });
```

[image]

**Clicking on the button will yield button click event. However, clicking on area other than button, will not yield any `ListView` click event anymore.**

May I know why is it so? Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make **both Rows and Buttons clickable**, set

```
android:focusable="false"
```

for your **Button**. The same goes for ImageButtons, RadioButtons, ...

> Android has been primarily designed for a large set of input methods.
>   The entire system is completely capable of working with no touch
>   screen. To navigate through the UI, the user can use a directional pad
>   which focuses Views after Views if and only if those Views are
>   focusable. **By default, all Android controls are focusable.** In order to
>   prevent having controls that are not focus-reachable, the ListView
>   will simply prevent the selection (and click) of an itemview. By
>   design, **the ListView blocks clicks of itemview** containing at least one
>   focusable descendant but it doesn’t make the content focus-reachable
>   calling setItemsCanFocus(true).

Here is the whole great explaination: **[Having several clickable areas in a ListView](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the preferred way (even according to the link provided in the accepted answer) is to set the android:descendantFocusability attribute to block focus from the root layout you're inflating within the adapter.  There can be potential situations where simply setting the focusable attribute to false on an individual element won't solve the problem, but the descendantFocusability attribute will.