# Why does setting a ListView's choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_NONE only work when posted as a Runnable()?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have been battling with a `ListView` (in a `ListFragment`) whose choice mode I want to change between `CHOICE_MODE_NONE` and `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`. Switching between the modes is fine, but getting the selected items to be deselected is tricky.

Several approaches are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754170/listview-selection-remains-persistent-after-exiting-choice-mode/20901048#20901048), but the only one I could really get to work was by setting the choice mode (`listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE)`) within a new `Runnable()` posted to the `ListView`.

That's great, but I don't understand why it works, and I am struggling to find more information. Could someone explain how and why this works? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can touch `View`s (modifying it's background, changing their content, drawing objects on them etc etc...) in main UI Thread only...

If you want to touch outside the UI Thread, then you need a `Runnable` action and post it to the `View` `Handler`...

and here may be your changing `ListView` choice mode in non UI `Thread` which obviously need a `Runnable` action but if you are doing this in UI Thread, directly you can call `ListView.setChoiceMode()`...

Comment: But isn't `setChoiceMode` running on the UI thread? If so, then shouldn't the update be visible? (i.e. it shows the selected items being deselected.)

It's only when I execute `setChoideMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE)` _outside_ the the UI thread that it seems to work.

Comment: I have this backwards - `view.post()` runs on the UI thread, right? So if I just call `myListView.setChoiceMode()` without `posting` it, where (which thread) does that run?!